# I cannot find the way to display triangle.setColor('yelow') and Triangle.setFillet(true)

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, extends

I have two problems with the Triangle class. I was able to display all the results when I test the
program but still I can get color and filled true/false.
I place the output the end so you can see what is happening.

I tried to solve it adding in the instant variables b o o lean Filled; then in the constructor try to
add after the sides, String color and b o lean filled, then tried to add in the main
system out print ln (triangle get Filled(), but still I was not able to find the answer.
Also tried to override get Color and Get Filled  but still i can find the correct solution.

Write a test program that create a Triangle  object with:
sides 1 1.5 1; color yellow; filled true and Display (1) the area, (2) perimeter, (3) color and whether (5) filled or not.

```
// Coding:
public class Exercise11_01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(1, 1.5, 1);
        triangle.setColor("yellow"); // No display in the output
        triangle.setFilled(true); // No Display in the output
             
        System.out.println(triangle);
        System.out.println("The area is " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is "  + triangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println(triangle);
    }    
}

// superclass: GeometricObject
package geometricobject;
import java.util.Date;

public class GeometricObject {
    String color = "white";
    boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    
    
    /** Construct a default geometric object */
    public GeometricObject(){
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    /** Construct a geometric object with the specific color and filled value */
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled){
        
        dateCreated= new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    
    /** Return color */
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    
    /** Set a new color */
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean
     its getter method is named isFilled */
    public boolean isFilled(){
        return filled;
    }
    
    /** Set a new filled */
    public void setFilled(boolean filled){
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    
    /** Get dateCreated */
    public java.util.Date getDateCreated(){
        return dateCreated;
    }
    
    /** Return a string representation of this object */
    public String toString(){
        return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color + " and filled: " + filled;
    }
}

//subclass-extends: Triangle
package geometricobject;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    // Instant Variables
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    //boolean filled;
    
    public Triangle() {
        //super();
        this.side1 = 1.0;
        this.side2 = 1.0;
        this.side3 = 1.0;
    }
    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) { // , String color, boolean filled)
        //super(color, filled);
        
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
        
        setColor(color);
        setFilled(filled);
    }

    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }

    public void setSide1(double side1) {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }

    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }

    public void setSide2(double side2) {
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }

    public void setSide3(double side3) {
        this.side3 = side3;
    }
    
    public double getArea(){
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2.0;
        return Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);
    }

    public double getPerimeter(){
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nTriangle: side1 = " + side1 + " ,  side2 = " + side2 + 
                " , side3 = " + side3;
    }
}
```

// My output:
Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0
The area is 0.49607837082461076
The perimeter is 3.5

Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You can use any of the methods inherited methods from the `GeometricObject` class, so to get the fill and color you can use this `System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());` and this `System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());`

Comment: I tried too but my output still no reflect those fields:

Comment: Here my output after I added your suggestion:                                                     
 Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0
The area is 0.49607837082461076
The perimeter is 3.5

Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0

Comment: That output looks identical to what is in your question. Are you sure that you added the correct code, where did you add it (Right after the other ptintln code?), and did you rebuild to get the new output?

Comment: First I run:                                    
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(1, 1.5, 1);
        triangle.setColor("yellow"); // No display in the output
        triangle.setFilled(true); // No Display in the output
        System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());
        System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());
        System.out.println(triangle);
        System.out.println("The area is " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is "  + triangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println(triangle);

Comment: Second: Triangle triangle = new Triangle(1, 1.5, 1);
        //triangle.setColor("yellow"); // No display in the output
        //triangle.setFilled(true); // No Display in the output
        System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());
        System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());
        System.out.println(triangle);
        System.out.println("The area is " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is "  + triangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println(triangle);

Comment: I tried a couple more thinks with your suggestion but still nothing. The output is always the same.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't show modifications in comments.

Comment: If I run the exact same code in your question with my additions I get the extra lines "The triangle is filled: true" and "The color is yellow". Please edit your question to show the latest code. If you are still not seeing the correct output then there is another issue that we cannot help with unless we have more information. It sounds like you are running an older versions of the program, or you have not rebuild the code before running it.

Comment: By the way, `java.until.Date` is now legacy. Using `java.time.Instant.now()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments, you can use any of the inherited methods from the GeometricObject class. To get fill and color you can simply use:

```
System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());
System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());
```

Like this:

```
Triangle triangle = new Triangle(1, 1.5, 1);
triangle.setColor("yellow");
triangle.setFilled(true);

System.out.println(triangle);
System.out.println("The area is " + triangle.getArea());
System.out.println("The perimeter is "  + triangle.getPerimeter());
System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());
System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());
```

The output shows the extra information about the fill and color:

```
Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0
The area is 0.49607837082461076
The perimeter is 3.5
The triangle is filled: true
The color is yellow
```

Comment: Sirifiend, You always were right. I found the error. Inside my source packages, I have several programs related to GeometricObject and a couple of testing programs that disable some Triangle program functions when I was trying to run it. After I cleaned/remove those test programs and run again with your answer. The program displays all the information that I need. I just learned that I need to create a new source package to avoid errors that later take me a lot of time to find out the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve in my Triangle program.  Inside my source packages, I have several programs related to GeometricObject and a couple of testing programs that disable some Triangle program functions when I was trying to run it. After I cleaned/remove those test programs and run again with your answer. The program displays all the information that I need. I just learned that I need to create a new source package to avoid errors that later take me a lot of time to find out the problem.
Below the Triangle program with other additional implementation and removing some methods not necessary in this case.

```
package geometricobject;
import java.util.Date;

public class GeometricObject {
    String color = "white";
    boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    
    
    /** Construct a default geometric object */
    public GeometricObject(){
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    /** Construct a geometric object with the specific color and filled value */
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled){
        
        dateCreated= new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    
    /** Return color */
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    
    /** Set a new color */
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean
     its getter method is named isFilled */
    public boolean isFilled(){
        return filled;
    }
    
    /** Set a new filled */
    public void setFilled(boolean filled){
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    
    /** Get dateCreated */
    public java.util.Date getDateCreated(){
        return dateCreated;
    }
    
    /** Return a string representation of this object */
    public String toString(){
        return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color + " and filled: " + 
               filled;
    }
}


package geometricobject;

// Create a Triangle class.
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    // Instant Variables
    // data fields: Three double sides 1, 2, and 3.
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
        
    // Construct a default Triangle object - No arg.
    public Triangle() {
        this.side1 = 1.0;
        this.side2 = 1.0;
        this.side3 = 1.0;
    }
    
    // Construct a Triangle Object with the specified side1, side2, and side3.
    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) { 
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
        
        setColor(color);
        setFilled(filled);
    }
    
    // Define Accessors 
    // Return side1
    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }
    // Return side2
    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }
    // Return side3
    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }
    
    // Calculate the triangle's area.
    // Return area.
    public double getArea(){
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2.0;
        return Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);
    }
    
    // Return the Triangle's perimeter.
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }

    // Return the string (toString Method) representing the triangle's sides. 
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nTriangle: side1 = " + side1 + " ,  side2 = " + side2 + 
                " , side3 = " + side3;
    }
}

package geometricobject;

public class Exercise11_01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(1, 1.5, 1);
        triangle.setColor("yellow");
        triangle.setFilled(true);

        System.out.println(triangle);
        System.out.println("The area is " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is "  + triangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The triangle is filled: "  + triangle.isFilled());
        System.out.println("The color is " + triangle.getColor());
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Triangle: side1 = 1.0 ,  side2 = 1.5 , side3 = 1.0
The area is 0.49607837082461076
The perimeter is 3.5
The triangle is filled: true
The color is yellow
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```